# Making multiple text files in multiple folders from a csv automatically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with many rows and column. I wanted to create one folder for each row and within that folder have two files:

1. First 5 columns
2. Next columns

I have been able to create two cases

1. I have been able to create two folders 'a','b' 'a' having all the files of first five columns. and vice-versa.
2. I have been able to create a single folder having the name of the time stamp. and all the files in it.

   import pandas as pd
   import os
   from datetime import datetime
   from datetime import timestamp as ts
   data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

   if '10' not in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
       os.mkdir(timestamp)
   if '50' not in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
       os.mkdir('50')

   def splitter(data, split = 3):
       timestamp = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())
       for i in data.itertuples():

   ```
       data_1 = pd.Series(i[1:split+1])
       data_2 = pd.Series(i[split+1:])
       data_1.drop
       #print(data_1)
       data_1.to_csv(r'10.txt'.format(i[0]+1),mode = 'w',index = False)
       data_2.to_csv(r'50.txt'.format(i[0]+1),mode = 'w',index = False)
   ```

   splitter(data)

I want to have name of different folders having time as their name to stop redundancy

Comment: What if you have 12 columns in 2 rows? How would it be arranged in that case?

Comment: it can be split in any manner 4, 8

Comment: it will have 2 folders

Comment: one for each row  and each folder will have two files having first 4 cloumns in one file and 8 coloumns in other file

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, one folder per row, this might do.

```
import csv
import os
with open('test.csv','r')as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)


    def splitter(data, split = 3):
        rowNumber = 0
        for row in data:
            if rowNumber == 0:
                rowNumber += 1
                continue
            os.mkdir("folder-"+str(rowNumber))

            # Split it and create individual files
            with open("folder-"+str(rowNumber)+"/"+"10.csv","w") as tfile:
                tfile.write(",".join(row[0:5]))

            with open("folder-"+str(rowNumber)+"/"+"50.csv","w") as tfile:
                tfile.write(",".join(row[5:]))
            rowNumber += 1

    splitter(data)
```

I removed the Pandas library as it didn't seem required. Rather used the CSV library. The for loop takes each row creates a folder for it and then the two required files.